# Questions about entries of symmetry matrix and skew-symmetry matrix..

Tags: matrices

For symmetry and skew-symmetry matrix, must entries of matrix be real number?

Suppose a matrix with first row 0  -2i and second row is 2i 0

It seems like that it is skew-symmetry,

Answer (score 0):

No, "skew-symmetric" and "symmetric" do not impose any particular condition on the field you're working over.  The matrix you've described is indeed skew-symmetric.

However, it's not necessarily the case that theorems about, say, symmetric real matrices still hold for symmetric matrices over other fields.  For instance, a real symmetric matrix is self-adjoint, but the equivalent condition for a complex matrix to be self-adjoint is not that it's symmetric but rather that it's Hermitian.

Comment: but eigenvalues for matrix that i mentioned are 2 and -2. Isn't eigenvalue for skew-symmetry 0 or imagery number?

Comment: As I said, theorems which are true for *real* skew-symmetric matrices are not necessarily true for *arbitrary* skew-symmetric matrices...